# Blacklisting i2c_hid does not work

Tags: linux, centos, kernel

I have a dell vostro 15 and I am setting up centos 7 in my laptop. After installation my touchpad is not working and I have referred online and lot of suggestions are given that I should try blacklisting the i2c_hid kernel module to get my touchpad working.

So I have tried this

```
// added in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
blacklist i2c_hid
install i2c_hid /bin/false    // in arch wiki it was mentioned that blacklist alone might not work if some other non blacklisted module loads this module
```

after this I tried to confirm if the config is correct by running

```
modprobe --showconfig | grep "^install" | grep "/bin"
```

the output of the command was

```
install i2c_hid /bin/false
```

So I would assume I have configured it correctly. After this I rebooted the machine and did lsmod and i2c_hid was again present in the output.

I am not sure if this will help me fix my touchpad issue but I want to know if I am doing something in blacklisting the module. I would need to do some more of this {nouveau for nvidia graphics card}.

Answer (score 0):

The module is probably being loaded in your initial ramdisk (initramfs).
To rebuild the initramfs in CentOS 7 for your running kernel which take into account the changes you made, run

```
dracut -f
```

and reboot.